# Can we identify all the characters in this video game legends poster?

Tags: character-identification, crossovers

I found this ["video game legends" poster](https://www.deviantart.com/patrickbrown/art/Video-Game-Legends-840410936) by Patrick Brown, which features a whole bunch of characters which appeared in video games:

[image]

I recognize some of the characters, but many are obscure to me. Observe that some of them originated from a video game (e.g. the Portal protagonist), and some of them didn't, but appeared in various video games all the same (e.g. Goku).

Who is everyone?

Comment: I've seen similar questions being asked, so I hope this is okay.

Comment: Mass identification questions are perfectly fine. Might be worth creating a labelled version of the image and posting it in a community wiki answer below to make this easier.

Comment: There's a reasonable list [here](https://i.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/ozhvh5/video_game_legends_by_patrick_brown/?limit=500)

Comment: @Wade - It's gonna get some downvotes. I don't think everyone likes these kind of 'fun' questions...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I wouldn't say they're *perfectly* fine. A minority of users in this community (myself included) consider them too broad and tolerate them by downvoting them since we cannot close them.

Comment: @Null Perfectly fine as in on topic and (currently, at least) not close worthy, not that they're universally accepted or liked.

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for the explanation, I didn't expect this (I already received about 6 downvotes). In any case, I'm sorry if I offended anyone with this question, I did not realize it was such a sensitive issue.

Comment: Here's a complete list of characters (as described by the artist on his own Youtube channel); https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqfH1mJTQ4Y

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For convenience, I've added some numbers to the image (click to enlarge):

[image: Image of dozens of video game characters at a pool party]

Here goes:

1. Licker from *Resident Evil*
2. 
3. A pair of zombies (I can't tell what from, though)
4. Commander Shepard from *Mass Effect*
5. Cloud Strife from *Final Fantasy VII*
6. A Korok from *Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*
7. Agent 47 from *Hitman*
8. Nathan Drake from *Uncharted*
9. Ellie from *The Last of Us*
10. Lara Croft from *Tomb Raider*
11. Cal Kestis from *Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order*
12. Tracer from *Overwatch*
13. Alduin from *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim*
14. John Marston from *Red Dead Redemption*
15. Michael De Santa from *Grand Theft Auto V*
16. The Joker as he appears in *Batman: Arkham Asylum*
17. Niko Bellic from *Grand Theft Auto IV*
18. Earthwork Jim's suit (Earthworm Jim himself isn't in it; see #80)
19. Deadpool
20. Mario
21. Pac-Man
22. Sackboy from *LittleBigPlanet*
23. An origami figure from *Heavy Rain*
24. The Watch Dogs logo from *Watch Dogs*
25. The Sole Survivor from *Fallout 4*
26. Claptrap from *Borderlands*
27. Emmet from *The LEGO Movie*
28. Chell from *Portal* (you can also see her hand emerging from a portal to the right of #74)
29. Yarny from *Unravel*
30. Isaac Clarke from *Dead Space*
31. Chun-Li from *Street Fighter*
32. Joel from *The Last of Us*
33. A Little Sister from *BioShock*
34. A Big Daddy from *BioShock*
35. Trevor Philips from *Grand Theft Auto V*
36. A Xenomorph from *Alien*
37. Luigi as depicted in the *Luigi's Mansion* games
38. Duke Nukem being attacked by a Facehugger
39. Gordon Freeman from *Half-Life*
40. Faith from *Mirror's Edge*
41. Goro from *Mortal Kombat*
42. Ezio Auditore da Firenze from *Assassin's Creed II*
43. The ducks from *Duck Hunt*
44. A set of blocks from *Super Mario Bros.*
45. Pikachu from *Pokémon*
46. Potentially Columbia from *Bioshock Infinite* but could reference a few things
47. Spider-Man
48. Alex Mercer from *[PROTOTYPE]*
49. Cole McGrath from *inFAMOUS*
50. Bowser from *Super Mario Bros.*
51. Scorpion from *Mortal Kombat*
52. Ratchet from *Ratchet and Clank*
53. Clank from *Ratchet and Clank*
54. Dogmeat from *Fallout 4*, holding an Iron Pickaxe from *Minecraft*
55. Kratos from *God of War*
56. Yoshi from *Super Mario Bros.* (or at least, a rubber ring in his likeness)
57. Arthur Morgan from *Red Dead Redemption 2*
58. Link as he appears in *Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*
59. Diddy Kong from the *Donkey Kong* series
60. Donkey Kong, playing the drums as in *Donkey Konga*
61. Crash Bandicoot
62. Sonic the Hedgehog
63. Solid Snake from *Metal Gear Solid*
64. Master Chief from *Halo*
65. Dr. Ivo "Eggman" Robotnik from *Sonic the Hedgehog*
66. Red from *Angry Birds*
67. The ball from *Rocket League*
68. Ciri from *The Witcher*
69. Princess Peach from *Super Mario Bros.*
70. The Dovahkiin from *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim*
71. Franklin Clinton from *Grand Theft Auto V*
72. Abraham "Abe" Lure from *Oddworld*
73. Geralt from *The Witcher*
74. Batman
75. Meat Boy from *Super Meat Boy*
76. Kakarot aka. Son Goku, from *Dragon Ball*
77. Max Payne from *Max Payne 3*
78. M. Bison from *Street Fighter*
79. Ghost from *Destiny*
80. A Pidgeot from *Pokémon*, making off with Earthworm Jim (see #18)
81. Mega Man

Comment: I'm tempted to say that 15th could be Indiana Jones, but I don't have much proof of it beside the fact that I saw him take that position, remove his hat and brush his forehead, on a Super Nintendo game.

Comment: @Clockwork My first instinct was Max Payne, but I couldn't be certain either, so I just left it blank.

Comment: 80 is covering 2 things I think, I guess the "worm" would be a Worm from Worms but it needs labelling.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - 80 is Pidgeot carrying Earthworm Jim (which is number 18)

Comment: Dogmeat is, AFAIK, in the first Fallout game. (I've not looked any further though)

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Dogmeat is in at least 1, 3 and 4 that I know of from the top of my head.

Comment: Number 2 appears to just be generic zombies as well. Slightly higher res [image here](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5edb18356cb927448d88a93f/1591499448720-OXA1J49CZ6C6K86MK42Q/VideoGameLEGENDS.jpg?format=2500w) (from the [artists website](https://www.patrickbrownart.com/shop/p/video-game-legends-high-quality-jpg-file)) if it helps anyone see what they are

Comment: My guess it that No. 3 are the zombies from Plants vs Zombies.

Comment: @fez I think at least the one on the left is from Doom (2016), judging by the sunken cheeks and scraps of his uniform on his arm.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think we can say this version of Dogmeat is from Fallout 4, because the person he's offering the pickaxe to is The Sole Survivor, also from that game.

Comment: I think 13 is Alduin, not Paarthurnax. If it's Paarthy, then the color is all wrong.

Comment: Emmet is also from Lego Dimensions, if we need a video game source. (Also, his name has 1 "t".)

Comment: @fez Zombies or Mummies?

Comment: Side note: I'm 99% sure Koroks already had that appearance in Wind Waker.

Comment: I have this terrible feeling I have seen that kind of graphics for #3 somewhere, but I can't remember where. It definitely was a game I didn't play.

Comment: Is it me or there's some kind of green ghost coming out of Geralt's cup, in front of him? Unless it's Abraham's fart?

Comment: #2 could be Dead Island zombies, since they're in a building similar to where that game starts and the iconic trailer takes place in.